# How can I make a condition like IF THEN statement after the WHERE statement in a PROCEDURE including variable

Tags: oracle, plsql

Here is my problem, I need to test a variable to know if it's a 0 or not, but i want to do it in a basic select that will go in a cursor.

Exemple of what I want to do (I already know that this can't work) :

```
PROCEDURE random(pi_d_var1 IN NUMBER) IS
 CURSOR L_CUR_age IS
  SELECT * FROM table t 
   WHERE t.age BETWEEN 18 AND 68
      IF pi_d_var1 != 0 THEN dosomething ELSE donothing  
     END IF;
```

Im sorry if you guys dont understand, I'll try to do a better formulation, tell me :)

Thanks you in advance for reading this !

Comment: What's the logical relation between table.age and pi_d_var1, moreover expected result ?

Comment: What kind of thing is "dosomething"? Part of the query, or a separate procedural step?